# 4-bit ECC algorithm

Tags: algorithm, embedded

Can anyone give a reference for a 4-bit ECC algorithm?

I need to implement one for an embedded Nand Flash driver.

Comment: Without telling us whose NAND you're using makes your question a little useless. There's no guarantee that all vendors will use the same ECC algorithm. For instance, I know of at least one Samsung NAND product which uses 22-bit ECC.

Comment: I'm not following why this is vendor specific. Sure, every vendor has its requirement, but I can implement a stronger ecc if I want, no? Right now, specifically, I am looking at a Samsung 512MB nand with page of 2K and block of 128K.

Comment: Another clarification, in case it is not the correct terminology, by 4-bit I mean that the algorithm can fix up to 4 erroneous bits. If this terminology is incorrect, I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: 4 erroneous bits out of how many bits in total?

Comment: It seems that 4 bits out of 256 bytes, but I am still waiting for the spec. According to what I read in the answer below I should use a RS(255,253) since I understand that there jargon is for the 8bit as a whole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is probably a [Reed Solomon Code](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Reed-Solomon_code). [Here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/pscico-guyb/realworld/www/reedsolomon/reed_solomon_codes.html) is a pretty good explanation of how they work, and [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#I0cABDTB4TA/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-4-stable/All/msp430-libc-1.0.20050912.tgz|fzfdk8WJTfI/msp430/share/mspgcc/examples/reed-solomon/nn4.c&q=reed-solomon+code) is some code that actually implements the algorithm. It isn't commented very well, sorry about that. Some google action will turn up more.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are reference implementations readily available for NAND Flash. Check out the implementations in the U-boot and Linux kernel repos.

drivers/mtd/nand/ is the path you want in the repos.